# Function not firing on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that takes 2 functions onclick. Here is my button:

```
<button id="btnNext" onclick="increment(); Next();">Next</button>
```

The increment() function works as intended on the first click but the Next() function does not. It does work as intended after first click. If I remove the increment() function, the Next() function works on first click. I have tried combining the functions but it gives me the same result.

The Next() function moves to the next form and the increment() function moves the scrollbar slider to the desired position.

Here are my functions:

```
var Next = function () {
    UserVM.Model.MoveCurrentToNext();  
}

var increment = function () {
    if (lastScroll < 240) {
        lastScroll += 40;
    }
    scrollpos.scrollTop = lastScroll;
}
```

Does anyone know what the reason is for this?

**UPDATE:** I added an alert to the Next() function. Now when I trigger the button it shows the next form when the alert box pops up but when I click ok, it returns to the previous form. This only happens when I click the button for the first time. Any reason for this? Anyway to solve it?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to create an event handler and call both functions from there?

Comment: Have you tried `onclick="Next()"` and then try to call `increment` from `Next` function?

Comment: `increment()` is not coded defensively.  It will fail if lastScroll or scrollpos is undefined.

Comment: I have a feeling it is a timing issue with the code.

Comment: Side-Note: It is generally bad for maintenance to use inline handlers with jQuery. It separates the *event registration* from the *event handler* (also losing features jQuery adds). Your code will generally be simpler and easier to maintain if you register your events using jQuery. This bug will likely simply vanish.

Comment: @Patel I have tried that. It gives me the same result

Comment: @Paul I have defined lastScroll and scrollpos

Comment: then it might be a timing issue as @epascarello has already mentioned. Check his answer out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel dumb. I figured it out, should have figured it out way earlier. I have the variable `lastScroll` in another function, so I just change it to the variable position - `var position = 0;`. Now it works. Sorry for wasting everyone's time. I'll leave this question up just in case any of your answers help someone else out.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why are you using two separate functions for a single `onclick` unit because if you want to do both the operations why don't you call the form redirection code in the same function.

```
var increment = function ()
{
    if (lastScroll < 240)
    {
        lastScroll += 40;
    }
    scrollpos.scrollTop = lastScroll;
    //form navigation
    UserVM.Model.MoveCurrentToNext();
}
```

> **HTML**

```
<button id="btnNext" onclick="increment();">Next</button>
```

Comment: I did that originally but I thought that may have been a cause to the problem. Anyway, I thought it was cool that I can call two functions in onclick. Plus I wasn't sure if I was going to use the increment function anywhere else. I changed it back to how I had it originally.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
var Next = function () {
alert("This is Next Function");  
}

var increment = function () {
    alert("This is Increment Function");
    Next();
}
```

```html
<button id="btnNext" onclick="increment()">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling it is a timing issue. Add a slight delay to give the scroll position to change. (Just an educated guess);

```
var Next = function () {
    window.setTimeout(UserVM.Model.MoveCurrentToNext, 100);  
}

var increment = function () {
    if (lastScroll < 240) {
        lastScroll += 40;
    }
    scrollpos.scrollTop = lastScroll;
}
```

Comment: Not a bad guess. I tried it but it did not work. I have written an update. Please check it out and let me know if you know what the problem is. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All provided answer work but I think this one is closer to what you need (without using other JS libraries neither making the functions to depend on others)

```html
<button id="btnNext" onclick="(function(){increment();setTimeout(next, 100)})()">Next</button>
```

Note that this solution is wrapping the call of both increment() and newxt() function inside another anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

remove the onclick attr and put this in your code js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click","#btnNext",function(){
    Next();
    increment(); 
  });
});
```